# Chef says cookbook doesn't exists when it does

Tags: chef, cookbook

In my runlist for one of my nodes, I have "recipe[logstash::server]". When I run chef-client on the node, the following error is thrown:

The following cookbooks are required by the client but don't exist on the server:
* logstash

When I run **knife cookbook list** I see logstash, and when I run **knife cookbook upload logstash -o vendors/cookbooks/** the cookbook uploads successfully.

Comment: The node is really connecting to the same chef server?

Comment: Yes, there is only one.

Comment: have you double checked versions?  Sometimes you can get that error when the version of the cookbook needed by the environment is not available on the server.

Comment: Had the same problem. Turns out one of my environments had this cookbook locked to a particular version with chef_environment's cookbook_versions. So it was a typo on my part.